# Desktop application allowing backup (syncing) of local folders onto Cloud Storage?

Tags: backup, storage, cloud-storage

(I find it odd that this question hasn't been asked already... I thought there were more people paranoid that I am...)

Anyway.

Is there a desktop application, that allows me to backup a given folder to a (Cloud) storage service (Amazon / Rackspace / ...) etc.. ?

Note: I am not looking for closed-source offering backup solutions, there are plenty.

I am looking for this combination instead:

1. Free application (open source)
2. Ability to chose cloud-storage providers

Any pointers would be really helpful !

Comment: How would you guarantee security? I'm sure all storage providers would use different authorization protocols and such...

Answer (score 3):

[**Unison** is a file-synchronization tool for Unix and Windows. It allows two replicas of a collection of files and directories to be stored on different hosts (or different disks on the same host), modified separately, and then brought up to date by propagating the changes in each replica to the other.](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/)

I don't understand why you would trust Amazon and not [Dropbox](http://www.getdropbox.com/) or [Mozy](http://mozy.com/home)

Comment: I have nothing against existing backup providers, just that I am a bit paranoid of they going down tomorrow.

My idea is fairly simple. If by chance this backup company decides to go down with some warning (lets say a month), how practical is it for me to get back all my data (probably in GBs) on my low-speed home connection ? Not really.

An open-source app that supports multiple-providers, can instead be asked to migrate all data from provider A to provider B in far less time.

Comment: I doubt they would do that for free. You could always use both Mozy and Dropbox. That way if one company folds you'll have a second backup.

Comment: I don't see how some application would move data from one server to another any faster, if that application is not running on either of those two servers. (Unless you're simply backing all data to multiple remote storage providers to start with, but then there would be no need to move any data either.)

Answer (score 0):

[Duplicati](http://www.duplicati.com/) seem to be able to do what you want, including encryption, and it's open source!